# Gridview Navigation through keyboard with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

suppose my gridview has 5 column and 10 rows. each column has textbox. when focus is in first textbox of first row then i want that if user press right arrow key the focus will move to next textbox in first row second column. when user will press down arrow then focus will move to textbox which is in the 2nd row and 2nd column. i could i achieve this by javascript. please give me concept which will be generic and that can be use in any page of same scenario.
thanks.

Comment: What is a "gridview"? HTML table, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Calctastic](http://phrogz.net/JS/Calctastic/) library uses this for inputs in HTML tables. (See example 2.) This is accomplished through the use of my [Grid Navigation](http://phrogz.net/JS/Calctastic/gridnav.js) library, which leans on some [very old cross-browser code](http://phrogz.net/JS/Calctastic/genlibsubset_calctastic.js).

At some point I will update this to use jQuery; until then you are welcome to take and modify the code as you like.

Note that I explicitly do *not* support (or recommend) right/left navigation using the arrow keys. Users need to use arrow keys to move the caret while editing text. If you hijack the right arrow key to move to the right input, it's going to be very confusing and annoying.